# Code error I'm unsure of what is causing it

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, error-handling, discord.js, bots

Alright, I'm a very new coder and I have an error message and I'm unsure of what it is. I've tried a lot of things. I'm unsure of what the issue is, I've checked my spelling but nothing seems to be out of the ordinary. The file I'm trying to make work in particular is the embed file, but there might be errors in the other parts causing errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS84C.jpg

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. , Instead of linking it to imgur, please  provide the error message you are seeing, a **minimal** code example that reproduces your error, and what behavior you are expecting, so the community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```js
message.channel.send({embeds:[/* your embed name goes here */]})
```

to send the embeds

Answer (score 0):

In the new version, you can't just use `message.channel.send(embed)` you have to be a little bit more speciic by adding `{ embeds : []}`

```js
message.reply({ embeds : [your_embed_goes_here]})
```

And if you have multiple embeds :

```js
message.reply({ embeds : [embed1, embed2, embed3]})
```